# How can I access/fetch all the details of a particular contact, if I already have his/her name with me?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Basically, I've a tableview which displays all the contact names (just like built-in contacts app in ios) stored on the device, in my app. I want to add a page which shows up when I click a cell in the tableview, and in that page I want to display all the details of that particular contact tapped in the tableview.

I've fetched all the contacts in the tableview using Contacts() in swift5. It was very easy. But now I want to retrieve (and show on new page) all details of any particular contact, which maybe variable for different contacts, for example some may have 3 numbers, some may have 4, some may have birthday some may not.
I tried searching on the internet a lot, but couldn't find anything suiting to me scenario. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: I suggest that you use a tableview. Each contact information will be contained in a custom cell (birthdayCell, PhoneNumberCell ...)

Comment: Make a struct and pass the data to other controller using that struct for a particular index.  While displaying check if value is not nil then display

Comment: Show your code. Show how you create the tableView, show your cell class. Based on what you have done, someone can help you with a solution. Nobody will waste his/her time giving you a solution based on guessing what you did.